# EL disabled by default in maven project

Tags: jsp, maven, jstl, el

I created an Eclipse Web Project using Apache Maven 3. I am experiencing problems with Expression Language. It is disabled by default and my attempts to enable it through web.xml are in vain.

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <el-enabled>true</el-enabled>
    <scripting-enabled>true</scripting-enabled>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

The only way I am able to make them work is with this scriptlet on top of JSP page.

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

The POM for my project is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>learn.filter</groupId>
  <artifactId>LearnFilters</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>LearnFilters Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>LearnFilters</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <port>8080</port>
            <path>/LearningFilters</path>
                <warFile>${project.basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}.war</warFile>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Is there any way I can enable them through web.xml or by default? Also, this kind of build creates two web.xmls!!! This gets really confusing. Please advice.

Comment: Have you installed m2e-wtp plugin in Eclipse ?

Comment: No....I am not using any plugins yet.

Answer (score 1):

What is you web.xml version? `isELIngnored` is false by default in 2.4 AFAIK. So use 2.5 or 3.0 namespace, and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the tag is the problem.

What you have is

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <el-enabled>true</el-enabled>
    <scripting-enabled>true</scripting-enabled>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

I think it should be "el-ignored" rather than "el-enabled". It has always worked for me. This tells the web container that it should NOT ignore expression language in jsps if it encounters any.

```
<jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <el-ignored>
                false
            </el-ignored>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
```

This is the web.xml equivalent of

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```